# Operating system in NOKIA phones

Tags: c++, operating-system, kernel, nokia, smartphone

I want to know what operating system NOKIA smart-phones use? Which programming language is used to write it and is it possible to do kernel level programming for these systems? Can we use C codes to change the system software?  Libraries are available or not? I have never coded for mobile phones. So if possible give me a link to the pages where these topics are discussed in detail. Thanks in advance.
EDIT: I want the details for NOKIA s60 v3 and v5.

Comment: Nokia uses a broad range of operating systems including S40, Symbian^3, Maemo, etc.  You'll need to be a bit more specific...like which phone are you talking about or what OS are you trying to target.

Comment: Also, most operating systems are written using a combination of C, C++ and assembly.  This is generally the case across the board regardless of whether you are talking about a smartphone or desktop OS.

Comment: I am targetting s60 v3 and v5.

Comment: First time it happened with me in stackoverflow.com. More then half an hour and no answers. Now only god can help.

Comment: @user417552: Besides that you already got the answer in a comment, I think it is just not the right place for that question. Google might be a better place...

Answer (score 1):

From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nokia_S60:

> The S60 Platform (formerly Series 60 User Interface) is a software platform for
>   mobile phones that runs on [Symbian OS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbian_OS).

> The S60 software is a multivendor standard for smartphones that supports
>   application development in Java MIDP, C++, Python and Adobe Flash.

Note that you'll have to register as a developer or jailbreak the phone:

> (S60v3) uses a hardened version of Symbian OS (v9.1), which has mandatory
>   code signing. In S60v3, a user may install only programs that have a
>   certificate from a registered developer, unless the user disables that
>   feature or modify the phone's firmware through third-party hacks that
>   circumvent the mandatory signing restrictions.

Comment: I have read all these in wiki and other sites. I want to know about the kernel used in these operating systems. I s it possible to modify the kernel. Do the libraries are available?

Comment: The Symbian OS uses its own kernel. Try searching for *Symbian kernel architecture* for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Nokia has Symbian kernel (i don't know about them much) and LINUX kernel like the one in N900 (using maemo and meego) though N900 is considered as a tablet-pc more than a smartphone and it has lots of modified kernels .